# Insert an selected image from gridview to mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I know how to upload and insert images using FileUpload ToolBox control.
 But this time I have to insert selected gridView item(an image) to mysql using asp.net. So First I select an image from gridview then I insert that image to 'image' table. Problem is Mysql Workbench can't open the inserted image. I predict the inserted data is not a blob data.
 And I think I'm missing some basic concepts of image insert.
 My codes are given below.
 Image data type is blob.
 How can I fix it?
 Examples will be much appriciated.
 Thanks.

```
protected void ImageInsert()
{
{
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Images(Image) VALUES ('"+CheckBox().ToString()+"')", con);
con.Open();
int s1 = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (s1 > 0)
{
imgUp1.Text = "Image Uploaded succesfully!";
}
con.Close();
}
}
private string CheckBox()
{
string url=null;
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvImages.Rows)
{
CheckBox chkBox = row.FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox;
if (chkBox !=null && chkBox.Checked)
{
Image img = (Image)row.Cells[1].Controls[1];
url = img.ImageUrl;
}
}
return url;
}
```